# ¿Por qué no me cargan los elementos en el comboValor cuando selecciono un elemento en el comboCam?

Tags: c++, qt, combobox

```
 connect(comboCampo,SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(const int &index )),this,SLOT(on_comboCampo_currentIndexChanged(const int &index )));

void MainWindow::on_comboCampo_currentIndexChanged(const int &index )
{

    query=new QSqlQuery();
    comboValor->clear();
    query->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM vertical;");
    bool res = query->exec("SELECT DISTINCT grupo FROM vertical;");

    if(query->exec()){
        while (query->next())
        {

            QString result =query->value(index).toString();
            comboValor->addItem(result);
        }

    }

    if (res == false)
    {
        QErrorMessage message;
        message.showMessage ( "SQL ERROR: " ,query->lastError().text() );
    }

}

//
```

Comment: Hola Antonio, bienvenido a [es.so]. El idioma oficial aqui es el español asi que debes traducir el titulo. Además has de explicar tu problema en el cuerpo de la pregunta, diciendo que problemas o errores tienes. Visita el [Tour] y [ask] para aprender como funciona este sitio. Un saludo

Comment: Porque no me cargan los elementos en el comboValor cuando seleeciono un elemento en el comboCampo?

Comment: Antonio, pulsa [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/66139/edit) para modificar tu pregunta, no en los comentarios. Recuerda leer [ask] para que tu pregunta sea de buena calidad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La macro `SIGNALS` genera un código que *parsea* la firma de tu función. Por defecto, Qt realiza una reducción de las firmas de las funciones para intentar conseguir una homogeneización. Piensa que de cara a una cadena de texto sería complicado encontrar similitudes entre las siguientes firmas pese a ser equivalentes:

```
void func(const int& a)
void func(int const& a)
void func(const int&)
```

En conclusión. `connect` debería quedar más bien así:

```
connect(comboCampo,
        SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)),
        this,
        SLOT(on_comboCampo_currentIndexChanged(int)));
```

Aunque en estos casos te puedes ahorrar `this`:

```
connect(comboCampo,
        SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)),
        SLOT(on_comboCampo_currentIndexChanged(int)));
```

Para más información acerca de la normalización de las firmas puedes consultar [este enlace](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#normalizedSignature)